# flashMessage on redirect on Symfony2 not working

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following code in my controller:

```
  $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'storeinfo',
                    'hayooo'
               );
  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AppMainBundle_item_detailed_view',  array('id' => $picture->getId(), 'caption' => $picture->getURLCaption())), 301);
```

and my twig looks like this:

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.get('storeinfo') %}
    <div class="comment-confirmation">
        {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('storeinfo') %}
            <p> <b> anjing banget </b></p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
     <p> Oopsie </p>
{% endif %}
```

so it goes to the first if block however inside the forloop, there is no flashMessage. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The FOSUserBundle does something like [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/layout.html.twig), you could also have a look at this great imlementation of a [`FlashListener`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/FlashListener.php)

```jinja
{% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
    {% for message in messages %}  

        {# Will print all your messages #}
        {{ message }}

        {# Will do something in particular for storeinfo if you want to #}
        {% if type is sameas('storeinfo') %}
            <p> <b> anjing banget </b></p>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```